# Execute command line script in module file

Tags: 8

I am using Drupal 8.9.5 and I need to compile a SCSS file using Gulp command in our module file.
If I execute the command from the command prompt, it works without any issues, but when I tried from the module, it didn't work. I have tried with `shell_exec()` and `exec()`.

The theme path is C:\wamp64\www\drupal895\themes\customtheme. Inside that directory, I have the node_modules directory, the package.json and gulpfile.js files. I am trying to use the following code.

```php
echo shell_exec('gulp');
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You won't have the same environment context, what you need a building step in your work process, which could be manual or automated in a pipeline.

Comment: Highly advise automating and scripting this.